# When is a distribution not a linear combination of independent product distributions?

Tags: probability-theory

By "RV" I will mean real-valued random variable.  Can someone give an example of $X, Y$ RVs such that there does not exist any constant matrix A and independent RVs $Z, Z'$ for which

$A*(Z, Z')^T=(X, Y)^T$ in distribution?

Is there an easy characterization of when this occurs or generalization to the n-variate case?

My attempt so far is to look at $X, Y$ which is not a multivariate Gaussian, but has Gaussian marginals.  But who is to say that $Z, Z'$ must have Gaussian marginals?  So this seems not to work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ Gaussian random variables such that the random vector $(X,Y)$ is **not** Gaussian. For any two independent random variables $Z,Z'$ and constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$X \stackrel{d}{=} a \cdot Z+b \cdot Z'$$

[Cramér's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Infinite_divisibility_and_Cram.C3.A9r.27s_theorem) implies that $(Z,Z')$ is Gaussian. In particular, any linear combination

$$A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} Z \\ Z' \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$$

is Gaussian. As $(X,Y)$ is not Gaussian, this means that there does not exist a representation as a linear combination of independent random variables. Obviously, this example can be easily generalized to the multi-dimensional case.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a characterization (or any non-trivial sufficient conditions) of when such a representation exists.